# Is it possible to host a server with DSL and a dynamic ip address?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dsl, dynamic-ip

I have a **dynamic ip** address with my DSL provider.
My domains are at GoDaddy.com and I use their total dns service.
So I guess this would be the equivalent of "ZoneEdit.com"

Is it possible to host the sites on a server that's connected to this DSL line?

Or **must** I have a static ip? *Yes, I'm aware the the static ip is easier route.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good article with a sample script how to make dynamic DNS update with zoneedit:

http://www.spencerstirling.com/computergeek/dynamicdns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CNAME record with a low TTL, which points to a dynamic DNS service.  There's a possibility of availability issues when your IP changes but it will work.  Some DNS administrators ignore low TTLs, which has the potential to introduce complication with a subset of users.

This is not a professional grade solution.  A professional grade solution begins with a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on your uptime requirements.  Most non-static IPs from providers don't actually change that often.  But when it does and you have to update your DNS record, it may take a day or until certain providers refresh their cache, even if the TTL is set low (lots of providers will just ignore TTL).

I recommend you just get a vps or shared hosting myself.  Besides your IP changing, you could have disk problems, power issues, etc.  There are different things that cause stuff to go down, a vps / shared hosting provider should be more prepared for these.

Also, depending on your agreement with your provider, you might likely be in violation of that agreement by hosting something (Though that doesn't often really matter).